# Swift - "Comparing non-optional value of type 'String' to nil" followed by "Thread 1: Fatal error:"

Tags: ios, swift, null, option-type

I want the title of *playerOneBtn*, which is in the ViewController file, to be the string which is stored in the variable *name* from the file *Player.swift* of the class *Player*. Like everytime when I open the ViewController, because the text can be changed in other Viewcontrollers by the user, thats why the code is in ViewDidLoad.

But it gives me an Error, because by running the app the variable *name* has a value of *nil*. Thats why I want to check if the variable *name* is nil or not and if, change it to *"PLAYER ONE"*.

Is there a way to check if the string is *nil*? I've read some other questions but unfortunately couldn't find out a working solution.

Or maybe some other part of the code is wrong, which is quite possible?

The first code is from the Playerfile, the second from the VC.

```
class Team {
    class Player {
        private var name: String

        init (n: String){
            self.name = n
        }

        func setName(n: String){
            self.name = n
        }

        func getName() ->String{
            return self.name
        }
    } 
    class PlayerOne: Team.Player {}
}

class TeamOneVC: UIViewController {
    var playerOne: Team.PlayerOne!

    override func viewDidLoad() { 
        if playerOne.getName() == nil {
            playerOne.setName(n: "PLAYER ONE")
        }
        playerOne = Team.PlayerOne(n: playerOne.getName())
        playerOneBtn.setTitle(playerOne.getName(), for: .normal
    }
}
```

> Line 7: (Warning) Comparing non-optional value of type 'String' to nil always returns false
>
> Line 10: (Error) Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Thanks!

[image: The PlayerFile]
  [image: The ViewController]

Comment: The name is not optional, so it can never be `nil`, which is what the compiler is telling you. `playerOne` however, is an implicitly unwrapped optional and you have never assigned anything to it, so it is `nil`. When you then refer to it in line 10 you get a crash because an implicitly unwrapped optional is force unwrapped. Also, this isn't java so don't use a private property with setter/getter methods. Just declare a public String property.

Comment: You probably should be assigning an object to the `playerOne` property from one of these "other view controllers"

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html

Comment: @Pailw11 Yeah I have, but all "other view controllers" can only be accessed  through this view controller, so the first time I go to this view controllers, the playerOne.getName() is nil and I need a way to like say that if it's nil, just add some text in it.

Comment: Also thanks for your help, I've changed everything you told me.

Comment: Hm, I can't set the name either..                                                                
`var test: String = "some text"
 playerOne.name = test` Gives me the same error (Thread 1..)

Comment: Ok, I've fixed it.. just changed `var playerOne: Team.PlayerOne!` to `var playerOne: Team.PlayerOne?` Thanks everyone!

Comment: Actually in my case my variable is  var districtName:String! = "", i added "?" or "!" to my string. Now the warning gone. Initially I write like this var districtName = "", in this case I'm getting same warning.